# Nuxt Link in Map Marker PopUp

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have a Google Map, with markers loaded. When I click the marker it shows a pop-up, which is great. Inside that pop-up I need a  so that it loads the next pages smoothly. But this doesn't work inside the content of the map marker as I have show below.

```
createMarker({
      lat: doc.lat,
      lng: doc.lng,
      content: `<div class="mapPopMarker-content">
                <div class="inner-content">
                  ${doc.name ? '<div class="name">'+ doc.name +'</div>' : ''}
                  ${doc.address ? '<div class="address">'+ doc.address +'</div>' : ''}
                  <NuxtLink to="/companies/${doc.id}" class="link">View</NuxtLink>
                </div>
                </div>`
})
```

When rendered, it just renders as HTML, and not an actual link here. How do I make this NuxtLink work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't render a `vue` code in the `createMarker` content property as it will be inserted as `innerHTML` and will not be compiled.

You can use [`nuxt-gmaps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-gmaps) library, and you can use `GMapMarker` component to add your code as default `slot` to it.

Comment: If I don't use Nuxt-gmaps, library, using Vue. How do I go about adding exactly?

Comment: This is not best practice, but I was able to use, `<button onClick="window.viewDetails('/companies/${doc.id}')" class="link">View Details</button>`  and then create viewDetails() function to handle the routing.

Comment: So, I think you don't use [`SFC`](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html).

Comment: If I can use a Vue File inside the createMarker that would be ideal. But not sure that's possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because the `content` is set to the `innerHTML`, so the Vue code will be inserted as it is without compilation.

Comment: Yeah not that i know of.